# Google speech recognation listener dont listen

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Hello  am running google speech recognizing service but it stops listening after seconds how can i restart it or make it loop

```
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplication());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,getPackageName());


    SpeechRecognitionListener listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener();
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);

   CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(1500, 500) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("Speech", "Timer.onFinish: Timer Finished, Restart recognizer");
            //mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
             mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
    };

mTimer.start();
```

Comment: How long did it lasted?

Comment: 2-3 seconds no sound environment it closes itself and how can i restart it countdowntimer doesnt effective??

Comment: Could you change this parameter to somewhat bigger number ??? `CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(1500, 500)`

Comment: increasing doesnt do anythng,,, i want it to restart it onerror but it doesnt doing anything also   @Override
        public void onError(int error)
        {
            Log.d("endof", String.valueOf(error));

            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

            //Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Remove your CountdownTimer. Put this in a method and when you want to start listening call the method.

```
try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Speech not supported on your device",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Speech output can be got in the onActivitySpeech method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //Handle the output
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: i want it loop so if any error recognation will restart... this is single start

Comment: check the resultCode value. If it is not RESULT_OK try to call the startActivityForResult containing method.